# How to back up email to local filesystem?

Tags: backup, email, imap

I am moving to a different email provider. It will be the same email address, though. How do I back up the full account, all messages and attachments, to the local filesystem so that I can restore it later?

Comment: also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310275/backup-emails-from-imap-in-readable-form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good way to maintain a backup of emails?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326221/100397)